# new ActionBarDrawerToggle when using AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

Today Google updated the AppCompat library to version 22.1.0, and we can now use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`.
This means we no longer need to have a `Toolbar` view in our activity layout.

The problem is that in order to create a Drawer toggle button, I cannot use `new ActionBarDrawerToggle` anymore, because it expects a `Toolbar` parameter, which will not exist.

How am I supposed to add the toggle button to the ActionBar now?

Comment: Out of curiosity - who's saying that *"we no longer need to have a Toolbar view in our activity layout"*? I can't find any reference for this.

Comment: The new `AppCompatActivity` already features a toolbar (which I believe can be removed/hidden if you want), so you don't need to add another one

Comment: The `AppCompatActivity` features an `ActionBar` per default. You still have to modify the Theme to `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` and add a `Toolbar` to your layout.

Comment: @AlexMomotov not yet

Answer (score 23):

A possible solution

Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle
            (
                    this,
                    drawerLayout,
                    R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                    R.string.navigation_drawer_close
            )
            {
            };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#f1f2f7"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Style :

```
<resources>


    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>

</resources>
```

It's important that your app inherit the AppCompat theme.

If you replaced the actionbar by a toolbar do not forget to put back the actionbar by removing this line in the styles.xml :

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Gradle :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

I put this code on github : https://github.com/bbouabou/AppCompatActivity-With-ActionBarDrawerToggle .

Comment: How do I get the hamburger icon? According to the material guidelines, it should be used, but this code gives you a simple back arrow?

Comment: @MrPablo: You probably missed something, this code should give you hamburger icon when drawer is closed and arrow when drawer is open.

Comment: @BrahimBouaboud yea, I went back and rewrote the code and it's working now

Comment: I am habituated with Toolbar. Suddenly, I got the same requirement for my current project. I searched a lot for couple of hours, finally got this to boost up my confidence. Thanks. :)

Comment: setDrawerListener is deprecated

Answer (score 5):

As per [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.Activity,%20android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout,%20int,%20int)), the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class from v7 features a toolbar-independent constructor:

```
public ActionBarDrawerToggle (Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

This will work with the default `ActionBar` provided through `activity`. So, as always, either:

1. you inherit from an action bar theme, and call `new ActionBarDrawerToggle(...)`;
2. you inherit from a `.NoActionBar` theme, instantiate/inflate a `Toolbar` object, and call `new ActionBarDrawerToggle(..., Toolbar t, ...)`

Looks to me that nothing changed with the `ActionBarActivity` refactoring.

Comment: really works after swithcing from v4 to v7 support library

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Android Studio's default Navigation Drawer setup, then I found success by changing `NavigationDrawerFragment.java`'s `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class from `v4` to `v7` in the `import` statement and omitting the `Toolbar` argument from the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor.

Comment: hi @SQLiteNoon, please can you show your new constructor. Mine does have these parameters (new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity, DrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,"open, "close"

Answer (score -3):

I couldn't find a way to use the AppCompatActivity's default toolbar, so the workaround I used was to use the `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` theme and manually add the toolbar to the XML like I was doing before.

Comment: Where have you read `AppCompatActivity` has a default `Toolbar`?